# Error #2032 displayed in html page

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a app which is used to testmicrophone.But when include in html page it displays Error #2032.How to resolve this.

This is the HTML code

```
  <div style="display: inline;float:center;">
                                    <object width="100" height="100">
                                    <embed src="mic.swf" width="250" height="250">
                                    </embed>
                                    </object>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Why do you think including this app in an HTML Page causes the error? How are you testing the app otherwise?  Does a specific line cause the error? can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Because when the APP is removed the error is doesnt show up.How will i get a stack trace of the html page?

Comment: what is the error message? does it show up in every browser? do you see it if all the files are used from the local filesystem (or in other words - can it be solved with adobe settings manager http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html ?)

Comment: Actually i got this error when i opened the page in my Ubuntu firefox.

Comment: just got the same error from `Flash Media Server 4\tools\multicast\multicastplayer\multicastplayer.html` while `multicastplayer.swf` embedded there just tells me i must specify an url

Comment: @wwwOzOk:Let me know the solution if u find any..Also now the error exists even on windows domain..

Comment: Just in case if any one want to know the solution.I just changed the name of the mxml file and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

It appears ww0z0k's comment likely points to the answer I believe your probably running into a flash player security issue, be sure you have the debug version of flash installed and working properly, one way to test would be to just throw an error

```
package
{
    import mx.core.Application;

    public class ThrowErrorApp extends Application
    {
        public function ThrowErrorApp()
        {
            super();
            throw new Error("this is wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

and make sure you see a dialog come up on top of the browser that shows your error, this would also contain the stack trace as requested by a previous poster.  Depending on how your source code is linked up the stack trace will usually point you to a line in question which will help resolve this issue, without that info it's impossible to say what spurred the error exactly, 2032 is not specific enough, check out more on this error here: http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/
Go to the flash player settings by right clicking and selecting Global Settings, then in the links on the left of the page that loads (go to advanced if it doesn't bring you right to a page) click on the global security settings in the trusted tab of the settings panel add a location and make it the local path to the swf/html folder (any parent folder will do as well).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the swf is from the export release.